# Empty Series when Attempting to Plot with Pandas and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm attempting to follow and work through [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w26x-z-BdWQ) by Wes McKinney.  I'm to the point where we're going through the baby names examples, and I'm having the same problems both in my code I'm writing and with [his code](https://github.com/estimate/pandas-exercises) (BabyNames.ipynb).

For reference, I'm on a Mac (OS X 10.10.1) using:

- Python 2.7.6
- IPython 2.3.1
- Pandas 0.15.2

I can successfully do all of this:

```
names = read_csv('baby-names2.csv')   # read the data in
boys = names[names.sex == 'boy']      # create boys list
girls = names[names.sex == 'girl']    # create girls list

# create a function
def get_quantile_count(group, quantile=0.5):
    df = group.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False)
    return df.prop.cumsum().searchsorted(quantile)

# call the function 
boys.groupby('year').apply(get_quantile_count)
```

This gives me output that looks like this (for brevity, only showing a small section of the data):

```
year
1880    [15]
1881    [15]
1882    [17]
1883    [17]
1884    [19]
1885    [20]
1886    [20]
1887    [21]
1888    [22]
1889    [22]
1890    [23]
1891    [24]
1892    [25]
```

I want to then plot this data, like this:

```
boys.groupby('year').apply(get_quantile_count).plot()
```

but it's giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Empty 'Series': no numeric data to plot
```

In watching the video, the data he shows does not have the square brackets [ ] around the numbers in the data frame.  I'm guessing this is what's causing my problems.

Anyone have any tricks on how to change this?  I was watching the video and writing the code myself, but the same thing happens if I run the provided notebook BabyNames.ipynb.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like I posted this question too early.  I stepped away from it for a bit then realized this was an easy fix.

The issue was the function searchsorted() was giving me an array back, and I only needed the single item in the array.  Easy enough.  Modified the function to be this:

```
# create a function
def get_quantile_count(group, quantile=0.5):
    df = group.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False)
    return df.prop.cumsum().searchsorted(quantile)[0]
```

Just used the index 0 to get the number out of the array.  Don't know why I was having such a hard time with this.  I guess that function must have changed its return type in the recent past?  Or is there some option I have that's set incorrectly?  Don't know, but at least this fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, used `.astype(float)` to solve the issue, but your way might be better.

```
boys.groupby('year').apply(get_quantile_count).astype(float).plot()
```